# wget - specify directory and rename the file

Tags: file, download, wget

I'm trying to download multiple files and need to rename as I download, how can I do that and specify the directory I want them to download to? I know i need to be using -P and -O to do this but it does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: What operating system you are trying this on ?
Also what exact command you tried ?

Comment: I'm writing this into a php script and running on unix.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it's too late to post my answer here but I'll correct @Bill's answer
If you read in "**man wget**" you will see the following

```
...
wget [option]... [URL]...
...
```

That is, common sense leads to realizing that

```
wget -O /directory_path/filename.file_format https://example.com
```

is the default that aligns with the wget documentation.

Remember: Just because it works doesn't mean it's right!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation and came across your question. I was able to get what I needed by writting a little bash script that parsed a file of urls in one column and the name in the 2nd.

This is the script I used for my particular requirement. Maybe it will give you some guidance if you still need help.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=URLhtmlPageWImagesWids.txt
while read line
do
    F1=$(echo $line|cut -d " " -f1)
    F2=$(echo $line|cut -d " " -f2)

    wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A.jpg -O $F2.jpg $F1

done < $FILE
```

This won't work actually because -O combines all results into one page. 
You could try using the --no-directories or --cut-dirs switch and in the loop process the files in the folder how you want to rename them.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget your_url -O your_specify_dir/your_name
```

Comment: you can try this ,
```wget http://unsplash.com/photos/U-i4KN7Oo68/download?force=true -O ~/U-i4KN7Oo68-rename```

Answer (score 0):

Like Bill was saying

```
wget http://example.com/original-filename -O /home/new_filename
```

worked for me !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## This may works for everyone

```
mkdir Download1
wget -O "Download1/test 10mb.zip" "http://www.speedtest.com.sg/test_random_10mb.zip"
```

## You need to use " " for name with space.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a little late to the party, but I just wrote a script to do this. You can check it out here: [bulkGetter](http://esausilva.com/2012/10/20/bulkgetter-a-script-wrapped-around-wget/)