# Can't get -P and -O flags working together for wget command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget

### System Information

- `wget` version: **1.21.2**
- OS: **Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS** (*WSL 2*)
- Directory Structure:

  ```
  home/
  ├─ test/
  ```

### The Issue

I have encountered a specific issue with the `-P` and `-O` flags, where the `-P` flag argument is completely ignored when used with the `-O` flag. For example, I have the following `wget` command:

> `wget -P test/ -O test.doc https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file-sample_100kB.doc`

I am running this command from the home directory. Here are the expected & actual outcomes:

**Expected Outcome**:

```
home/
├─ test/
│  ├─ test.doc
```

**Actual Outcome**:

```
home/
├─ test/
test.doc
```

However, if I remove the `-O` flag from the command, I get the expected outcome, but of course, it won't be renamed.

> `wget -P test/ https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file-sample_100kB.doc`

**Outcome**:

```
home/
├─ test/
│  ├─ file-sample_100kB.doc
```

### Conclusion

It seems like there is clearly something happening between the `-P` and `-O` flags, where I can't use both of them simultaneously for some reason.

I have also tried absolute paths, and that has not worked for me either.

Comment: Why not just use `wget -O test/test.doc https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file-sample_100kB.doc`?

Comment: The answer to your question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75204079/20947816)

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might use `-O -` to instruct `wget` to get file emitted to standard output and then redirect to file inside catalog consider following simple example

```
mkdir -p test # create test catalog if it does not exist
wget -O - https://www.example.com > test/example.html
ls test/*.html # shows test/example.html
```

However be warned that this will always download and overwrite target file.